# Assembly: Exit Code Wrong

Tags: assembly, x86-64, exit, system-calls, darwin

I am learning Assembly and I created a simple exit program.

```
.section __DATA, __data
.section __TEXT, __text
.globl _main

_main:
  movl $0x2000001, %eax   #System call exit, offset by 0x00000
  movl $1, %ebx           #Exit Return code
  syscall                 #Wakes up kernal to run the systen call
```

How ever after running the file, echo $? returns 0

Assemble and Link command:

```
as exit.asm -o exit.o
ld exit.o -e _main -o exit
./exit
```

Comment: What operating system is this for? It looks like you’re trying to target Darwin?

Comment: @icktoofay yeah I am currently running OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exit code goes in `%edi`, not `%ebx`. (I’m not sure of a canonical reference for this; I just used trial and error.)

Comment: OS/X 64 bit uses [System V AMD64 ABI](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) conventions . The first parameter in a syscall is passed as `%rdi`. Exit takes one argument (the return code), thus it is placed in `%rdi`